# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Cannot execute the query

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012, openrowset

I have this sql code. It updates a specific cell in an excel file.

```
SET @cmd = 'UPDATE OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=C:/sompath/file.xls;HDR=NO;IMEX=0;'',''SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9 FROM [Sheet1$]'')
            set [F1] = ''Hello World''
            where [F1] = ''<field1>'''
EXEC(@cmd)
```

This piece of code executes successfully in 32bit but fails in 64bit server (MSSQL Server 2012). I get this error in 64bit:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "No value given for one or more required parameters.".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot execute the query "SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9 FROM [Sheet1$]" against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

The `file.xls` is an excel file created in a 32bit pc.

Can someone help me with this issue. I've been searching around the net but really did not get the solution or even some guide to resolving it. If this question has already been posted and answered, just kindly post the exact link please.

By the way, I have already installed the ACE provider and all those settings needed.
In fact, this code works fine but not with the UPDATE statment:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
set @cmd = 'SELECT * FROM
            OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0'',
            ''Excel 12.0;Database=C:/sompath/file.xls;HDR=NO;IMEX=0'',[Sheet1$])'

EXEC(@cmd)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting issue.  The following article seems to provide a lengthy discussion, with various resolution attempts and finally a solution (at least for the OP).  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/ace ... Good luck.

Comment: You have *both* the 32 and 64 bit ACE OLEDB 12 drivers installed?

Comment: @billinkc, I am not the admin but I think there is only 64bit version of ACE installed. Will that matter?

Comment: @billinkc, we'll give it a try to install 32bit version of ACE.

Comment: I finally found the answer today. I just resaved the excel file from 64bit MS Office. The provider used is still ACE OLEDB 12 64bit driver. We tried using 32bit ACE but still got the problem. So, we reinstalled the 64bit then just resaved the excel file as mentioned. Hopefully this will also help those who are encountering the same issue. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excel file must be created/resaved from a 64bit MS Office. That's all!

Comment: By the way, I really don't mean to answer my own questions. I marked this as an answer so that others, having the same problem, will be guided and easily find answer to such issue. This is the second time.

Comment: Leaving it open would be a pain.